# Inserting multiple arrays into same array section

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a problem when I try to insert using one loop arrays into a specific place in the JSON. The app is designed to create a dictionary with main terms and their subterms (synonyms) . I succeeded to create the main terms but I can't add subterms. one entry contains main term and their translations and then subterms are encapsulated in "Subterms" sections with translations.
The final JSON file format I need is :

```
{
   "glossary":{
      "0":{
         "id":4,
         "English":{
            "term":"accountability ",
            "definition":"An obligation or willingness to use power"
         }
      },
      "Subterms":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "English":{
               "term":"behavior change communication",
               "definition":"The strategic use of communication approaches"
            }

         }
      ]
   }
```

I want to insert multiple Arrays with a loop (in the example above is just English) into "Subterms" but no matter what I try is not letting me access that position.

```
PHP code:
         
<?PHP 
$posts = array();
$subterms = array();
................

for($i = 0; $i < $val['maxentry']; $i++)
{
    if ($i==1)
    {
        $dataheadenglish = $db->getRecFrmQry($queryheadenglish);
        $headenglish = array (
                'term'=> $dataheadenglish[0]['term'],
                'definition'=> $dataheadenglish[0]['definition'],
                )

        $posts[] = array(
        'id' => intval($dataheadenglish[0]['row']),
        'English'=> $headenglish,
        );
    }
    else 
    {

        $dataenglish= $db->getRecFrmQry($queryenglish);
        if(!empty($dataenglish))
        {
            $english= array (
                    'term'=> $dataenglish[0]['term'],
                    'definition'=> $dataenglish[0]['definition'],
                    );
        }else $english=array();

        // same for all languages to be inserted

        $subterms[] = array(
        'English'=> $english,
        'Arabic'=> $arabic,
        'Turkmen'=> $turk,
        );
    }
}
?>
```

I tried with :

```
$posts['Subterms'] = $subterms;
$posts['Subterms'][] = $subterms;
array_push($posts["Subterms"],$subterms);
```

but the subterms appears before posts(aka headterm)

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "Subterms": [
            {
                "English": [],
                "Arabic": {
                    "term": "\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0633\u0627\u0621\u0644\u0629",
                    "definition": "",
                    "source": "",
                    }
                },
                "Kurdish_Badhini": [],
                "Kurdish_Kurmanji": [],
                "Kurdish_Sorani": [],
                "Turkmen": []
            }
        ],
        "0": {
            "English": {
                "term": "accountability ",
                "definition": "An obligation or willingness to use power responsibly and be held accountable for one's actions, both as individuals and as organizations.",
                
            },
```

It should appear part of "0"
Thank you

Comment: And what was the result of trying? It's unclear what "not letting me" actually means in practice. Do you get an error? Unexpected output? Please explain what actually happens when you run the code

Comment: the Subterms appears before headterms wheni try $posts['Subterms'] = $subterms;

Comment: If it should appear under the index `0` (as part of it), then `$posts[0]['Subterms'] = $subterms;` would seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning you showed a pattern of JSON you need, but at the end you said 'It should appear part of "0"'. Based on you example of JSON, I'll assume you wanted to say "past of".

If it got it right, the Subterms are being put before the "0" because it's exactly what you are telling it to do.

You are testing if `$i` is equal to `1`, and because your `for` is starting with `$i=0`, your `else` will be happening before your `if`, so your subterms are being put in the array first.

```
if ($i==1) // because of this
{
  // your code
}
else 
{
  // your code
}
```

My suggestion is to change this test from `$i==1` to `$i==0`, so your `if` will happen first.